# Implementing own signup and login system for apps

Tags: rest, web-services, authentication

I'm creating an app in which you are supposed to signup/login to use it. Now I'm implementing a restful webservice for it and I'm not sure whether I'm going the right way. My workflow is:

To signup, the user types in his credentials like username, email and password. The app hashes the password and sends a post request containing the credentials as json to my webservice and the webservice saves the new user to the database.

To login into the system, the app sends a get request including the parameters username and hash of the password to the webservice, compares the hash values and returns an appropriate response code for success oder fail.

The communication between app and webservice is secured by ssl.

Is this the right and secure workflow of a signup/login system? If not, why is it not secure and can you recommend another workflow? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The most important part should be that your web service is only reachable via https.
I assume you are talking about a mobile app.
The app should not hash the password, the web service should do it and then store the user.
Mobile apps can be reverse engineered and then you know how to hash your passwords.
So to create a user in a restful way would be to send a POST request with username, email and password in the body.

For example **POST /users**

```
    {
      "username": "john-doe",
      "email": "mail@example.org",
      "password": "some password"
    }
```

For authentication/authorization you might consider OAuth 2 but that takes a huge amount of time to implement.
Another option would be to have another REST resource called access-tokens.
So whenever you need to authenticate you do a POST /access-tokens request to create an access token.

**POST /access-tokens**

```
    {
      "username": "john-doe",
      "password": "some password"
    }
```

**Response**

```
    {
      "access_token": "9d91c97fc0f98a6311f101246e252ab3230c261c2af",
      "expries_in": 3600
    }
```

Then the mobile app needs to take care of that it will always create a new access token shortly before it expires. OAuth 2 has also refresh tokens for this purpose which are delivered together with the access token. Then you can retrieve a new access token just by sending the refresh token to the web service.
Once authenticated you need to include the access token in the Authorization header in every request to the web service that needs authentication.